# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar las posiciones 3 y 4 de cada una de las sublistas contenidas en una lista?

Tags: python

```
lista=[['10.10.10.1', '4', '10', '44', '44', '1', '0', '0', '00:37:52', '0'], ['55.55.55.55', '4', '85', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'never', 'Idle'], ['88.88.88.88', '4', '101', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'never', 'Idle']]

for items in lista:
    lista2 = [] 
    for item in items:
        lista2.pop(4)   
        
print(lista2)
```

Sabrán de algún metodo para realizarlo o algún ejemplo que me puedan proporcionar.
#Muachas Gracias!!

Comment: `nueva = [sublista[:3] + sublista[5:] for sublista in lista]`

Comment: Gracias Candid Moe, la solución es muy buena, sabes  cuál es el tema que debería buscae en específico para  hacerlo por mi mismo.?

Comment: El tema se llama `slices` de listas, también sirve para `string`, `dataframes` y otros elementos.